# google youtube api installation problems

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

when I did `sudo pip3 install google-api-python-client` it successefully installs but when I try to do `import google.oauth2` it doesn't find it. It just says `ImportError: No module named 'google'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip3` was using the wrong python, so I had to specify exacly which python version I had to use, in my case; `python3.5`